# Remove <p> and <br> from the_content?

Tags: wordpress

I have problem to remove `<p>` tag from `the_content` after upgrading to wp 3.6...

I'm used this in my theme function and worked fine, now this filter does not work,

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the priority:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop', 99);
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop', 99);
```

Comment: @MilanMilosevic If you're using the TinyMCE Advanced plugin, try unchecking this option: `Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the HTML editor`